# Display on GUI with Tkinter (Python)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I use the following code to print some data from a json file (from a api)

```
for search_result in search:
    print("Score:", search_result.score, "| URL:", search_result.url,)
```

As result I get something like this:

```
Score: 0.35096988 | 
URL: http://abc.n1989_12_7_rev.jpg
```

It's possible to display the same data on GUI? For this I have to use Tkinter

Comment: Yes, it's definitely possible.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? Where's the effort?

Comment: @Nae something like this is not working    w = Label(master, addPic())
        w.pack()         mainloop()

Comment: Yes, it's certainly possible. Your question is too broad. Try getting started with Tkinter, you can ask specific questions when you run into problems.

Answer (score 0):

type the following:

```
for search_result in search:
    text = str("Score:", search_result.score, "| URL:", search_result.url,)

from tknter import *
root = Tk()
label = Label(root, text = text)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's possible.

(If you want a more specific answer, you'll have to ask a more specific question.)